# How can I ON/OFF Autorenewal Subscription programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

How can I ON/OFF Auto-renewal Subscription programmatically. Like Apple music manage subscription does

Comment: As per my knowledge you have to perform all the operations form iTunes account not from App.

Comment: How does Apple music does " Auto-renewal " "On/Off" in app account